# Anonymous state variables versus topic variables in Raku

Tags: raku

In January 2020 I had written this code

```
my @a = ( 1, { ([+] 1 .. ++$ ) / [×] 1 .. ++$ } ... Inf)[^7];
say @a.join(' + ') ~ "=" ~ [+] @a;
```

to express the following mathematical series in Raku:

[image]

The code works correctly:

```
1 + 1 + 1.5 + 1 + 0.416667 + 0.125 + 0.029167=5.070833
```

Now I've replaced the anonymous state variable `$` with the topic variable `$_` to see if it works the same. It didn't:

```
1 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5=4
```

I would expect the `$_` to increment itself just like the anonymous state variable `$` does, but it didn't.

Could someone explain why
the `$` works out in this particular code but the `$_` doesn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** The code is working as it is supposed to. I'll explain what's going on below. Trying to use `$_` instead of a state variable is not going to work out.

> It looks like the `$_` doesn't even increment itself like the anonymous state variable `$` does.

It doesn't increment to the same values, but it does increment as it should.

The sequence begins:

```
1, { ([+] 1 .. ++$ ) / [×] 1 .. ++$ }
```

The first value in the sequence is `1`. The block is then executed to get the rest of the sequence's values, with `$_` set to the prior value. (I know you know this, but I will be very explicit and detailed in this answer so it's easy for you to spot your error, and easier for other readers who may not know Raku at all to try follow along.)

The first execution of the value generator block will generate the second value in the sequence. `$_` is assigned `1`, and the block execution, with the two `++$_`s replaced with the value they evaluate to, becomes:

```
([+] 1 .. 2 ) / [×] 1 .. 3
```

The `[+]` reduction coerces its RHS to a list, and then adds all the numbers in that list. `1 .. 2` yields the list `(1,2)`, and the sum of all its numbers is of course `3`.

The `[×]` reduction coerces its RHS to a list, and then multiplies all the numbers in that list. `1 .. 3` yields the list `(1,2,3)`, and the product of all its numbers is of course `6`.

So the overall expression evaluates to:

```
3 / 6 # which is 0.5
```

To get the *next* (third) value of the sequence the block is executed again, this time with `$_` assigned `0.5`.

Here are all the steps, broken out into separate pieces:

```
$_ = 0.5;
say ++$_;          # 1.5
say ++$_;          # 2.5
say list 1 .. 1.5; # (1)
say list 1 .. 2.5; # (1 2)
say [+] 1;         # 1
say [×] 1, 2;      # 2
say 1/2;           # 0.5
```

So the *third* value in the sequence is *also* `0.5`.

The *third* execution of the block, to get the 4th value in the sequence, is identical to the prior one (because `$_` is again set to `0.5`) so the result is again `0.5`. And so on, ad infinitum.

---

> I've searched a bit the Internet including the official Raku documentation, to understand the subtle difference between `$` and `$_` but I couldn't understand it. Could someone explain it?

For now I'm going to provisionally assume you know the differences -- a state variable maintains its state for the execution lifetime of its enclosing closure, but `$_` is just a lexical variable, the same as one declared with `my`, so is reset each time its enclosing closure is re-entered during its lifetime -- but were just confused because you thought `$_` wasn't incrementing (or perhaps other details such as `list 1 .. 2.5` yielding `(1,2)`). If that assumption is incorrect -- if you want someone to further elaborate on some difference you're not sure about between state variables and "ordinary" (non-state-maintaining) lexical variables, or between the `$_` variable and others, please comment. Thanks.

---

The sequence you're producing is such that the Nth term is calculated based on knowing N. An incrementing state variable is precisely the right tool. In contrast, knowing the value of the prior term looks to me to be of no help at all, which in turn suggests using `$_` isn't either (unless you assign a state variable's value to it, but why?).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The paragraph `To get the next (third) value of the sequence the block is executed again, this time with $_ assigned 0.5.` summarizes why the series kept on printing 0.5 all the time. But most importantly, it reminded me of the fact that the `$_` was taking the value of the previously calculated result.  Whereas the `$` must be keeping its value unaffected by the computation going on inside the generator block, so `++$` would increment  by 1 at each invocation of the generator block :)